# Visual Studio 2015 installation problem on Macbook Pro 2015 (Windows 10 by parallel)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I failed to install visual studio 2015 on my MacBook Pro 2015. The error message is like:
Update 3 setup blocked:  "Update 3 requires a member of the vs 2015 family to be present or is being blocked by another condition of your computer."

My Machine:  Macbook Pro 2015, RAM 8GB, SSD: 128, Windows 10 running By Parallel Software (Like VMware).

**Error message picture**
[image: Error message picture]

**My SSD space situation**
[image: My SSD space situation]

Comment: But, have you installed Visual Studio (the big guy)? It looks like that's just the Update3 setup.

Comment: **@Salam is your issue fixed?**

Answer (score 0):

double-check that vs is already installed before running the update file, check that parallels is allowed to have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar if not the same issue. I installed VS2015 with Update 3. There was no other VS version or edition in the PC - so you can say this is a fresh install. On starting VS, it prompted me to get KB3165756 (14.0.25431.0) and the next thing I got was: -

"Setup Blocked - Update 3 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer"

Here is what I did to get around the problem -

1. From the command prompt, type "vs14-kb3165756 /uninstall". (Don't use the /repair 
   option as this won't work.)
2. Choose Repair.
3. Let it run until finish.

Hope this helps.